# Saxon API: Modifying XML document

Tags: java, xml, saxon

I want to modify an XML document via the Java Saxon API.

I am starting from a DocumentInfo, drilling down to NodeInfo-s that I want to change. This works fine. However, I didn't find an API that allows me to change attributes of these nodes.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon's NodeInfo api doesn't provide methods to modify dom.

Anyway why do you want to use Saxon's proprietary api to modify xml. use DOM or XOM.